# Change in dependency property from code is not displayed

Tags: c#, wpf, button, dependency-properties, word-wrap

I've created a button, which is supposed to support wordwrapping. My XAML code for the button looks like this:

```
<Button x:Class="POS.TouchScreen.UI.Elements.TouchButtonWPF"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="buttonGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" BorderBrush="#FF8A97A9" Margin="4"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <TextBlock Name="ButtonTextBlock" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
               Text="{Binding ButtonText, Mode=TwoWay}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap">
    </TextBlock> 
</Button>
```

I've implemented the property as shown below:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText", typeof(string), typeof(TouchButtonWPF), new UIPropertyMetadata("Button",new PropertyChangedCallback(OnButtonTextChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(OnCoerceButtonText)));

private static object OnCoerceButtonText(DependencyObject o, object value)
{
    TouchButtonWPF button = o as TouchButtonWPF;
    if (button != null)
        return button.OnCoerceButtonText((string)value);
    else 
        return value;
}

protected virtual string OnCoerceButtonText(string value)
{
    return value;
}

private static void OnButtonTextChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TouchButtonWPF button = o as TouchButtonWPF;
    if (button != null)
        button.OnButtonTextChanged((string)e.NewValue, (string) e.OldValue);
}

protected virtual void OnButtonTextChanged(string NewValue, string OldValue)
{
    this.ButtonTextBlock.Text = NewValue;
}        

public string ButtonText
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
}
```

Inserting an instance of the TouchButtonWPF looks like this

```
<tse:TouchButtonWPF ButtonText="OK" FontSize="16" Height="77" HorizontalAlignment="Left"x:Name="buttonOk" Width="85" />
```

This works perfectly and the button text appears correctly. However when i assign the ButtonText from C# code, the text is not updated. I'm assigning the variable as shown below.

```
 touchButton.ButtonText = navButton.Caption;
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Note that the event handlers have been implemented when it didn't work initially, can't figure out if these eventhandlers are needed at all for the functionality i try to attain?

Look forward to read your replies :)

Comment: Any debugger insights? Is `OnButtonTextChanged()` getting called?

Comment: I've copy pasted your code and it works okay with and without the eventhandlers, are you sure the navButton.Caption use different text than the initial text? :)

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you are setting a Dependency property directly (`this.ButtonTextBlock.Text = NewValue`).

Up until you did this, the value of this.ButtonTextBlock.Text was set to a `Binding`. Replacing the binding with a local value deleted the binding, and the Text will no longer respond to the original binding expression.

replace - `this.ButtonTextBlock.Text = Value;`

with - `this.ButtonTextBlock.SetCurrentValue(TextProperty, value);`

This will set the value without blowing away your bindings

Comment: Hi Dean. Thanks for your reply.

I tried changing 
`this.ButtonTextBlock.SetCurrentValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, NewValue);`
To
`this.ButtonTextBlock.Text = NewValue;` 
However i still have no text displayed, when i assign the property from code.